# How to return a promise from a Hapi handler

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have a very simple Hapi server that returns a Promise that when resolved calls reply(), I understand that this is possible from its documentation: https://hapijs.com/api#route-handler

The problem is that the Promise seems to not get resolved (and consequently I don't receive a response) until I refresh the page a couple of times or after a really long time. The promise returned by check_ips works as expected so it seems to be something related to how Hapi handles it.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const ping = require('net-ping')

const server = new Hapi.Server({ debug: { request: ['error'] } });
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.connection({ port: port, host: 'localhost' });

const session = ping.createSession();

check_ips = function(ips) {
    var pings = []

    for (var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
        pings.push(new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
            session.pingHost(ips[i], function(err, target)  {
                if (err) {
                    if (err instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError)
                        fulfill(false)
                    else
                        reject(err)
                } else {
                    fulfill(true)
                }
            })
        }))
    }

    return Promise.all(pings).then(function(results) {
        response = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
            response[ips[i]] = results[i]
        }

        return(JSON.stringify(response))
    })
}

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/check_ips/{ips}',
    handler: function(req, reply) {
        if (!req.params["ips"]) {
            return reply({"error": "No IPs received"})
        }

        ips = req.params["ips"].split(",")
        return check_ips(ips).then(reply)
    }
});                                                                                                                         

server.start(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

Comment: This seems to run fine on my machine. May I ask which IPs you are using? What version of Hapi do you have? As a side note, please be aware that you are polluting the globals namespace when you declare `response = {}`, and `ips = req.params["ips"].split(",")`. In each case these items can be declared as a `const`. You could also say `const check_ips = function(ips) {...`.

Comment: That is weird. I've been trying 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for example. I'm using hapi v16.4.3.

Thanks about the side note. I have not been paying attention to this but it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure whether the question is still relevant for the OP.

The issue probably has nothing to do with Hapijs or Node.js. It seems to be with the rejection handling, i.e. not having a `catch` in the route.

I've rewritten your function without side effects to make sure it always returns.

```
const pingHost = (ip, cb) => {
    cb(ip % 3 === 0 && {});
};

const check_ips = function (ips) {
    return Promise.all(ips.map((ip) => {
        return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
            pingHost(ip, (err, target) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err instanceof ping.RequestTimedOutError) {
                        fulfill(false);
                    } else {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                } else {
                    fulfill(true);
                }
            });
        });
    }))
        .then((results) => {
            return ips.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
                return { ...acc, [curr]: results[i] }
            }, {});
        })
};
```

Normally it works fine:

```
check_ips("1,2".split(",")).then(console.log); // {1: true, 2: true}
```

Then it, expectedly, fails:

```
check_ips("1,2,3".split(",")).then(console.log)
```

Adding a `catch` clause prevents it from failing:

```
check_ips("1,2,3".split(",")).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

So in order to properly fix it, I'd start investigating what's the error type that being returned by `pingHost`, that causes `Promise` to be rejected.